# Prevent using IE8 with JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

Is there a way in JAVASCRIPT (not jquery) to stop navigating a webpage in IE8 ?
( if i use jquery, a error appears : **SCRIPT5009: jquery is not defined**.).

In a company is still using IE8, They want to left behind little by little, so they need to send an ALERT when the user start navigating an specific webpage.

Note: Works perfectly in IE9 and Chrome
Regards

Comment: jQuery works fine in IE8 - at least anything prior to version 2

Comment: "jquery is not defined" typically means that you have calls to `jquery` object before you've loaded the jquery.js script.

Comment: You should use the jQuery version that supports IE8.

Comment: I'm sure there's a way, but unless this is a web application with a login and NOT a website for public consumption, then I would highly recommend you not doing that. While an individual home user should be able to upgrade without issue, a lot of companies (especially bigger ones) have corporate IT people who control what browser their employees can use. Hence, the employee has no option to upgrade until the IT governance people go through some big huge process. Better to degrade gracefully. I can tell you, you would be surprised that there are fortune 500 companies still using IE 8.

Comment: In chrome works well and  IE9 works lika a charm.

Ie8 DOESNT

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put scripts inside tags like this. These tags say run these scripts on versions of Internet Explorer that are below 9. So, you could write a script that posts a notice on your page about using outdated browsers.

```
<head>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="outdated-browser-notification.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
```